# Tableau: Difference between 2 sets

Tags: tableau-api

I have two different data sources (Users and Shipments). I wish to display all the users who didn't receive any shipment for a specific month which will be selected by user.

Comment: Man, you're going to be a little more specific. What do those databases looks like? What fields each table has? By different sources you mean like one PostgreSQL and an mdb file, or 2 tables from the same source?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with structured data, you can use Tableau's data munging features. See [this Tableau Knowledge Base article](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/Creating-Joins). Also, Tableau can support joins across different data stores, a.k.a Data Blending. See [this Tableau video](http://www.tableausoftware.com/videos/data-integration) for more on data blending.

Also based on your question, I believe you must be relatively new to Tableau. I was in your position about a year ago. Watch Tableau's free On Demand Training videos on its website.